# Вычисление Хэш`а в python

Tags: python, алгоритм, хеширование, методы

Привет, stackoverflow. Пишу реализацию хэш-таблицы на питоне и столкнулся с такой проблемой: один метод (`get_hash`) почему-то возвращает разный хэш внутри класса и снаружи. Вынесение в отдельный класс не помогает. Этот метод реализует полиномическое вычисление хэша(a^1 + b^2 + c^3 + c^4  и т.д.) / len(слово) Все нужные опорные принты уже внутри. Заранее спасибо, вот сам код:

```
class Hashtable:
    def __init__(self, size=29):
        self.keys = [[]] * size
        self.values = [[]] * size
        self.size = size
        self.hash_key = 13

    def get_hash(self, something):
        something = str(something)
        return sum([ord(something[i]) ** (i + 1) for i in range(0, len(something))]) % self.hash_key

    def add_hash(self, key, value):
        print(" ")
        index = self.get_hash(key)
        print("adding ", key, "with index", index)
        self.keys[index] = self.keys[index] + [key]
        self.values[index] = self.values[index] + [value]
        print("keys  ", self.keys)

    def find_hash(self, key):
        print("___starting searching___")
        print("received key is: ", key)
        index = self.get_hash(key)
        print("index:", index)
        for i in range(0, len(self.keys[index])):
            print("key:", self.keys[index][i], "\t", "value:", self.values[index][i])
            if self.keys[index][i] == key:
                print("I find it!: ", self.values[index][i])
                return self.values[index][i]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.values)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "values " + "".join(str(self.values))


def main():
    HashTable = Hashtable()
    print(HashTable)
    HashTable.add_hash("23", "21")
    print(HashTable)
    HashTable.add_hash("2456", "hello")
    print(HashTable)
    HashTable.add_hash("7452", "aye fartuk v masle")
    print(HashTable)
    HashTable.add_hash("2357", "eeee")
    print(HashTable)
    HashTable.add_hash("3521", "eeee")
    print(HashTable)
    print(len(HashTable))
    HashTable.find_hash("3531")
    print("\n Hasing test:")
    print(HashTable.get_hash("3531"))
    print(HashTable.get_hash("3531"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Собственно, что не так-то? Проблемы в том, что значение вашего хеша для `3521` отличается от `3531` (третья цифра `2 != 3`)? Или в том, что ваш хеш для 3531 = хешу 2456? Это опечатка или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Такой вывод должен быть? ```received key is:  3531
index: 2
key: 2456   value: hello

 Hasing test:
2
2```

Comment: На будущее, кстати, в Python для простых типов уже определены функции хеширования. Вызовите для вашего ключа функцию [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) - и не нужно своих методов писать.

Comment: Да, я просто перепутал символы)

Comment: @Михаил ну я тогда отвечу, и мы закроем вопрос, вы не против?

Answer (score 2):

Вы заполняете хэш значением "3521", а ищите в нём значение "3531", отсюда и выходит ошибка вывода.

Comment: Ок)123456789241